# The button doesn't start a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-button

I want to start a new activity when i press the button, but when i press it my app crashes!

Where is the Problem?

Here is the code!

```
public void onClickButtonListener() {

    button_play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play_button);
    button_play.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(".SecPage");
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
    );


}
```

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: For future reference, please post LogCat messages (error log messages) to help us better understand the problem you are encountering.

Comment: u need to study or search  before posting question here

Answer (score 2):

Your Intent should have two parameters. The current activity and the activity it is going to.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecPage.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the following issues,

**Make sure you have specified your source and destination classes,**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**Make sure you have added an activity tag in the manifest file,**

```
<activity
            android:name=".ActivityA"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        </activity>
```

**If you are using the Activity class in a different package add the full package name,**

```
<activity
            android:name="com.silverlining.bionot.ActivityA"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to invoke a custom action with this constructor for Intent:

```
public Intent (String action)
```

Make sure you are using the full custom action string, something like `com.google.app.myapp.SecPage`.

According to [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String)),

> **public Intent (String action)**
>
> Create an intent with a given action. All other fields (data, type,
> class) are null. Note that the action must be in a namespace because
> Intents are used globally in the system -- for example the system VIEW
> action is android.intent.action.VIEW; an application's custom action
> would be something like com.google.app.myapp.CUSTOM_ACTION.